# AND-OR in same statement - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new in prolog and writing a simple program that suggest a song to a person. The rule I'm trying to write is "**Suggest [Song Link] of [Genre] genre if mood is [Happy] and [Person] is alex OR [Person] is quinn or [Person] is martha.**"

In prolog I've written it as:

`song('link of song'):-mood(happy),person(alex),person(quinn),person(martha).`

and I've written this rule:

`suggest(M,P,S):-mood(M),person(P),song(S).`

So when I call `suggest(happy,quinn,G,S).` it prints out all the values and not the one that I want. How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

```
song('song link 1'):-mood(happy),(person(alex);personality(quin);personality(martha)).
song('song link 1'):-mood(sad),(person(alex);personality(quin);personality(martha)).
```

but when I run `suggest(happy,alex,S).` it prints out each link 3 times.

Where: `suggest(M,P,S):-mood(M),personality(P),song(S).`

Comment: `,` is `AND` use `;` for using `OR` .`song('link of song', jazz):-mood(happy),person(alex),person(quinn),person(martha).` is "Suggest [Song Link] of [Genre] genre if mood is [Happy] and [Person] is alex AND [Person] is quinn AND [Person] is martha."

Comment: @Ch3steR even if I write `song('link of song', jazz):-mood(happy),person(alex);person(quinn).` it still doesn't work correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attached my approach below :

```
suggest_song('link1',pop,happy,X):- mood(happy) ,( X= (alex) ; X=(quinn) ; X=(martha)),!.
suggest_song('link2',jazz,sad,Y):- mood(sad) , (Y=(alex) ;Y=(quinn)),!.
suggest_song('link3',rock,gloomy,Z):- mood(gloomy) , Z=(chester).



mood(happy).
mood(sad).
mood(gloomy).

person(quinn).
person(alex).
person(martha).
person(chester).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
?- suggest_song(Link,Genre,happy,quinn).
  Genre = pop,
 Link = link1

?- suggest_song(Link,Genre,happy,alex).
  Genre = pop,
  Link = link1

?-suggest_song(Link,Genre,sad,alex).
  Genre = jazz,
  Link = link2

?- suggest_song(Link,Genre,gloomy,alex).
   false
```

> `suggest_song(Link,Genre,Mood,Person)` is suggest song link `L` of genre `G` if the mood is `M` and the person is `P`.

Hope is what you were looking for.

Comment: just to clarify, there's *two* things there. **`,`** is the *and*, and **`!`** is the *cut*. It can also be written `, !`.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to write out in English what each predicate is for.  It is often helpful to use the phrase "... is true when ..." in your description.

For example, you might describe your `suggest(M,P,G,S)` predicate as follows:

> suggest(M,P,G,S) is true when song S of genre G would be suggested to person P when they are in mood M.

Then you can define a clause for each possible way that this predicate could be true.  There is an implicit OR relationship between the clauses of a predicate - at least one of the clauses needs to be satisfied for the predicate to be true.  Although it is possible to use the semicolon to define OR relationships, it is often easier and clearer to define multiple clauses instead.

For example, if you wanted to define a clause that recommended "Take Five" as a jazz song for alex or quinn when they are happy, you could define clauses like this:

> suggest(happy, alex, jazz, take_five).
>
> suggest(happy, quinn, jazz, take_five).

I don't understand the meaning of your `song` predicate.  Can you describe its meaning using the "is true when" language?  For example:

> song(S, G) is true when ...

If you want to use `mood` and `person` as predicates too, then you should also define what conditions would make them true as well.

Comment: Got it.  So, you might have a clause like this:  song(take_five, jazz).

Comment: `song(X,Y)` implies that song `X is of Y genre`. You got the rest of it right. What I want is to have AND and OR in the same statement for example `Suggest song if the person is quinn OR martha OR alex and mood is happy`. So, `Song :- mood(happy) AND person(quinn) OR person(martha) OR person(alex)`. There are some songs that are only for Alex and Quinn and not for martha.

Comment: That is correct. I've it written like `song('link of song', jazz):-mood(happy),person(alex),person(quinn),person(martha).` Also there are more people not only alex, quinn and martha.

Comment: It sounds like your definition of song says that the song 'link of song' belongs to the jazz genre only under some conditions involving people and moods, which doesn't make sense to me.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by mood(happy).  Is mood another predicate that you have defined previously?

Comment: ignore the genre for now. Lets say `a songT belongs to alex or quinn if mood is happy` so when I say suggest a song for alex who is happy I should get songT in return. How can I write this?

Comment: I would write two clauses, like this:  

suggest(good_song, happy, alex).
suggest(good_song, happy, quinn).

Then, if you query suggest(Song, happy, alex) it would answer with a proposed value for Song.  Since the line breaks don't show up correctly in comments, I added these clauses as examples in my original answer above.

Comment: The issue is if I write song('take_five',happy,alex): mood(happy),person(alex);person(quinn).` the problem is `;` is not working as an OR here as I've `,` and `;` in one line.

Comment: You can use parentheses to group the OR'd conditions together.  I think the real problem is that mood(happy) is not what is needed in this clause.  You could write something like `song('take_five', Mood, Person) :- Mood=happy, (Person=alex; Person=quinn).`

Comment: I've updated the question see the update part to know where the problem is.